# Is creating a new scope in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, dependency-injection, thread-safety

I need to start multiple tasks to process some data. And each task has to use a new scope. So currently I resolve a `IServiceScopeFactory` and then `CreateAsyncScope` from it inside the tasks:

```cs
Task Process(IServiceScopeFactory factory)
{
    await using var scope = factory.CreateAsyncScope();
    ...
}
...
Task.Run(() => Process(_serviceScopeFactory));
...
```

The question is - is this thread-safe? Or perhaps it is best to `CreateAsyncScope` in the main thread and pass it to the task manually?

```cs
Task Process(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ...
}
...
await using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
Task.Run(() => Process(scope.ServiceProvider));
...
```

Being searching the internet but couldn't find any tips about this.

Comment: Let's turn this question around: why shouldn't calling a method on the (singleton service) `IServiceProvider` not be thread safe?

Comment: @Steven, it's not the method which could be not thread-safe, but perhaps some global states that could be corrupted. So far while studying the source code for DI I haven't found anything potentially dangerous. The problem is that currently, in my project, I do observe some multithreading problems and wanted to make sure that I haven't missed something in DI and the issue is somewhere else. Surprisingly, I also didn't find any official docs, articles or questions regarding this moment. No mentions at all.

Comment: Considering the code you posted, I'm very confident this is -and will always be- thread safe, even though the MS docs might not explicitly state this. `IServiceScopeFactory` is a singleton, provided by the framework, intended to be called in a multi-threaded situation. The `CreateAsyncScope` extension method does not access global state-it only calls `CreateScope`. If `CreateScope` wasn't thread safe, we'd all be in a lot of trouble (its used all over the place). I believe your threading issues have a different source.

Comment: @Steven, my thoughts are the same, just wanted to make sure, since it isn't mentioned anywhere. Hoped that perhaps someone else stumbled upon this like me.